# jTextField validation in java

Tags: java, swing

I my app I have many of jTextFields. How can I validate all of JtextField?

I try something like this:

```
if((jTextField1.getText.length()<3) || (jTextField2.getText.length()<3) ||(jTextField1.getText.length()<3) ......){

     ........

 }
```

What is a best way to validate text fields ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Put all the fields in a `List` of some kind and loop over them
- Use one or more `InputVerify` to perform post validation of the field, see [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for more details
- Use one or more `DocumentFilters` to do real-time validation, see [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [DocumentFilter Examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a callback, like when 'losing focus' event is fired:

```
jTextField1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        JTextField f = (JTextField)e.getSource();
        if((f.getText.length()<3) || (f.getText.length()<3) ||(f.getText.length()<3) ......){
             // ........
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    }
});
```